# MySql Session Provider - What are the locking columns for?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, session-state

The MySqlSessionProvider class does a lot of work for us but I'm having trouble finding documentation on the database structure. I know what the structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
     (
         SessionId       Text(80)  NOT NULL,
         ApplicationName Text(255) NOT NULL,
         Created         Datetime  NOT NULL,
         Expires         Datetime  NOT NULL,
         LockDate        Datetime  NOT NULL,
         LockId          Integer   NOT NULL,
         Timeout         Integer   NOT NULL,
         Locked          YesNo     NOT NULL,
         SessionItems    Memo,
         Flags           Integer   NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT PKSessions PRIMARY KEY (SessionId, ApplicationName)
     )
```

But I can't find any specifics about what the `Locked` column functionally does. Is the session temporarily closed? Read only? Reserved? Why is it a half hour before the `Expires` date?

Answer (score 0):

I feel bad answering my own question but I think I found it.

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx):

> The Locked, LockDate, LockDateLocal, and LockCookie fields are used to lock concurrent accesses to a session.

It's all about concurrency.

I was assuming this was a MySql feature, it turns out to be an Asp.Net feature with a connector for MySql.